# Exporting the output of sqoop into a text file on local

Tags: bash, shell, sqoop

I am trying to get the count of rows in a *mysql* table and trying to get the count of data into a text file onto local machine.

I am using the below command:

```
sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:mysql:url -username -password \
           --query"select count(*) from test" >> data.txt
```

I am getting the following output:

```
------------------------
| COUNT                |
------------------------
| 7548757              |
------------------------
```

I am looking for just the number in the output file as:

```
7548757
```

Nothing other than the count. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Does this work? `sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:mysql:url -username -password --query"select count(*) from test" | awk  '/\\|/ && $2 ~ /[[:digit:]]/ {print $2}' `

Comment: yes @Inian it was working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output data is uncomplicated, so there's dozens of ways to do this, and here's a few:

1. Using `tr`:

   ```
   sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:mysql:url -username -password \
              --query"select count(*) from test" | 
   { tr -cd '[:digit:]' ; echo ; } >> data.txt
   ```
2. `grep`:

   ```
   sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:mysql:url -username -password \
              --query"select count(*) from test" | 
   grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' >> data.txt
   ```
3. [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

   ```
   sqoop-eval --connect jdbc:mysql:url -username -password \
              --query"select count(*) from test" | 
   numgrep -l /0../ >> data.txt
   ```

Output is the same for all three:

```
7548757
```